# JavaScript regex string replace resulting in "$1" instead of word

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

I'm trying to append HTML outside of each emoji character by searching for emoji characters in a string. My regex seems to detect them but is replacing them with "$1" instead of the actual emoji character. Here is my JS code:

```
    var regex = /(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g;

    string.html(string.text().replace(regex, '<span class="emoji">$1</span>'));
```

I'm hoping anyone with regex experience can help me here.

Comment: Replace `$1` with `$&` as you need to replace with the whole match value.

Comment: Your regex does not include a capturing group.

Comment: Please produce the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce your problem. There is no reason to include this massive unwieldy regex.

Comment: @meagar well in this case the regex *is* the problem. However it's true that had the OP tried to come up with a smaller regex there's a good chance he'd have realized what the problem is :)

Comment: @Pointy The regex is not the problem, the replacement pattern is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew has answered my question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well sure, but without seeing the regex itself it's less clear. Also the problem *could* be fixed by changing the `(?: )` group to a plain capturing group.